# Change the width of DropDownButton in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp

When I set the Width and Height of DropdownButton,the DropDownButton Downarrow was hidden because of less width.

What I have tried is:

```
dropDownButton.Width = 17;
dropDownButton.Height = 30;
```

I want dropDownButton width must be 17 and the down arrow must be visible .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the padding value

```
    <DropDownButton Margin="10,10,10,10" Width="17" Height="30" Padding="-15,0,0,0"></DropDownButton>
```

[image]

I publish the code to [github](https://github.com/lindexi/lindexi_gd/tree/15af922b55e564c853842238be4a682f66b6fe6f/LeceaberheafeKeacafiwhajaibaiwhi) and you can find the complete MainPage.xaml code.

Comment: @PremKumarShanmugam If you think my answer can help you, please click the up vote and accept the answer.